# Implementation of Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Define $g_{n}(x) = \frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^{2}x^{2}}$. I want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} g_{n}(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$. To do this, I define $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & x \in (0,1] \\ \frac{2}{x^{2}} & x \in (1, \infty) \end{cases}$. I then claim that $|g_{n}(x)| \leq f(x)$, $\forall x \in (0,\infty)$. To do this, when $x > 1$ this is true. My question is on the proving for $x \in (0,1]$. Namely, argument is as follows:
$
\begin{align}
\\
\sin(nt) \leq nt , \forall t \in (0,\infty) \\
\implies \int_{0}^{x} \sin(nt) dt \leq \int_{0}^{x} nt dt \\
\implies \frac{1}{n} \left( 1 - cos(nx) \right) \leq \frac{nx^{2}}{2} \\
\implies \frac{1 - \cos(nx)}{n^{2}x^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{2} = f(x)  
\end{align}
$

Moreover, $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{5}{2} < \infty$. Hence, DCT tell us that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} g_{n}(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_{n}(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} 0 \mathrm{d}x = 0$. I would like to know if $f(x) \geq g_{n}(x) \forall x \in (0,1]$ by the way I have shown and if the argument I have given is complete. 
Also, what does it mean for $f \in C_{0}([0,\infty))$?

Comment: Your argument is very clean. You probably know this, but you could have performed the same argument by splitting the intervals as $(0,\epsilon),$ and $[\epsilon,\infty)$ for any $\epsilon>0.$

By the way, $f\in C_0([0,\infty))$ means $f(\infty)=0$, which is obvious given that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Is there a general definition for $C_{0}(X)$, where $X$ is some set?

Comment: $$C_0(X) = \{f:X\to X : f\text{ continuous}\} $$

Comment: I thought that was $C^{0}(X)$, right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\sin^2(nx/2)}{(nx)^2}\,dx \stackrel{nx\mapsto z}{=}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\sin^2(z/2)}{z^2}\,dz = \frac{C}{n},$$
so you do not really need the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\cos t-1+\frac  {t^{2}} 2$ for  $t >0$. The derivative of this function is $-\sin t+t$ which is positive. Hence the function $\cos t-1+\frac  {t^{2}} 2$ is incerasing. Since its value is $0$ when $t=0$ we see that $\cos t-1+\frac  {t^{2}} 2 \geq 0$ for  all $t \geq 0$. Put $t=nx$ to get the desired bound for $t \in [0,1]$.

Your function $f$ is not even continuous at $x=1$ so it is not in $C_0([0,\infty))$. $f \in C_0([0,\infty))$ means that $f$ is constant and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: What is the significance of $\cos t - 1 + \frac{t^2}2$? Why are we comparing $\cos$ to its Taylor polynomial? Also, I do not believe the OP claimed that his dominating function $f$ was in $C_0([0,\infty))$, but was only asking what $f\in C_0([0,\infty))$ meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use trigonometric identities to get
$$
\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^2x^2}
=2\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}2}{(nx)^2}
\le 2\frac{\min(1,\frac{nx}2)^2}{(nx)^2}
=\min\left(\frac12,\frac2{n^2x^2}\right)
$$
which directly gives an integrable upper bound.